# Can we change size of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Can we change size of an array in  java . i am confused. every one know about array : we can't change the size of an array.

but after writing this code i am confused.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
        int[] array1 = {1,1};

        System.out.println("befor : " + array1.length);   //I get 2
        array1 = array;
        System.out.println("intialize : "+array1.length); //I get 11

        for(int a : array1) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        System.out.println("after : " + array1.length);
    }
}
```

if we can't change the size of an array then we are supposed to get Runtime: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error at

```
array1 = array;
```

but i got output as:

```
befor : 26
intialize : 11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
after : 11
```

Comment: That's not changing the size of the array: it's just assigning a different value to the reference. This is like changing your friend's phone number stored in your phone: it doesn't *actually* change your friend's number, it just calls a different phone.

Comment: You didn't *move* the array, you changed a reference. `array1` now refers to the previously-allocated array at `array`.

Comment: `array1=array;` what this does is it assigns `array1` to reference `array`. That means now they are both pointing at **the same** array. You're not changing the size or anything.

Comment: While Java doesn't expose pointer arithmetic like C/C++, Java still uses pointers (or references)

Comment: An array, a sequence of consecutive, indexed values is an Object in java, with a fixed `length`. A variable of say type `int[]` - without the length -, can hold any actual array object. Such a variable just stores an Object handle. Other languages have a more elaborate type system with  index info: Pascal, or Algol68 (that has both a flex row of ints and for instance a row 7 to 14 row of int).

Comment: Watch this video to understand what's happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8IeMYsdgAY&ab_channel=NathanSchutz

Answer (score 0):

**Array1:**

Index->Value

0->A

1->B

2->C

3->D

4->E

Array 1 size = 5

**Array2:**

Index->Value

0->X

1->y

Array 2 size = 2

You need to be clear about the idea behind when we talk about immutability in arrays.

**Array1 = Array2?**

‘=’ is assignment operator. This means when you write the above line, you are deciding to replace entirely array1. There won’t be any reference of what Array1 had before after this line.

“if we can't change the size of an array then we are supposed to get Runtime: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error at”: You would not get this since you have assigned new values to Array1.

Array1 now does not even remember that it consisted of 5 values during its birth.